# Youtube to mp3 Converter VB

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I'm getting errors on my VB code:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        WebBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.youtube-mp3.org/")
        Button1.Enabled = False
    End Sub

    Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted
        Dim text As String = WebBrowser1.DocumentText

        If text.Contains("submit-form") Then
            Button1.Enabled = True
        Else
            Button1.Enabled = False
            MsgBox("Could not connect to the internet!", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Error")
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("youtube-url").SetAttribute("value", TextBox1.Text)
        WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("submit").InvokeMember("click")
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Dim dl_link As HtmlElement = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("dl_link")
        Dim links As HtmlElementCollection = dl_link.GetElementsByTagName("a")
        Dim url As String = links(0).GetAttribute("href")
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(url)
    End Sub
End Class
```

My Errors are:

> Error  2 Handles clause requires a WithEvents variable defined in the containing type or one of its base types.
>
> Error  3 'WebBrowser1' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.
>
> Error  3 'WebBrowser1' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.
>
> Error  3 'WebBrowser1' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.
>
> Error  3 'WebBrowser1' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.

Comment: You don't have a webbrowser control named WebBrowser1, what is so hard with the error message?

Comment: The error messages are clearly saying that WebBrowser1 is not declared. Where do you think it is declared?

Comment: Thats what **copy-paste** code can do...

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare your objects into the form.
Simply create a webbrowser, by dragging it from your toolbox.

Comment: Thanks, appreciate it.